# How to provide Google ADP credentials at run time to Dataflow jobs using custom containers?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow

I built a custom container for executing a Dataflow (Python) job using [this](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/using-custom-containers#using_base_image) guide. Turns out this container needs the environment variable `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` to be defined and be pointing to the ADC file `application_default_credentials.json` for the job to execute on GCP. Instead of embedding these credentials in the image, is there a way to more securely provide these credentials to the container at runtime, when Dataflow executes the job? If not, are there any other alternatives?

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing more secure than NOT providing secret to the container. Use the built in authentication mechanism to increase the security. Don't use the secret key file hard to manage, store and protect.

To achieve that, create a template (or a flex template) and run it with the command `--service-account-email`

Comment: I have already provided a value for `service_account_email` in my `PipelineOptions` that is also inside the container. Should it not be able to use that for authentication and hence not require separate ADC credentials through the JSON file?

Comment: If you want to increase the security, JSON file should not use, except in rare use case

Comment: Right, and that's the reason for my question above. How do I go about this?

Comment: It's my answer. User dataflow templates. You can't customize your service account if you directly deploy to dataflow your code

Comment: But how will the Docker container I'm using as an input to the pipeline (using the PipelineOption `sdk_container_image`) read the `service_account_email` credential provided to the template when it's not reading it without a template?